# In a React app, how do you use reactive variables inside a requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

This would be trivial in vanilla js, but I'm new to React so I don't understand how I should approach this.

I'm trying to animate a square using the Canvas2D API (like a basic left-to-right animation). But the trick is that I want to be able to control the size of the square with a GUI without interrupting the animation.

Here's my code. I'm using Leva for the GUI. The `size` variable isn't updated inside the RAF loop, but it is updated in the DOM.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useControls } from 'leva';

export default function SquareCanvas() {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const { size } = useControls({ 
        size: { value: 10, min: 1, max: 50}, 
    });
    let canvas, ctx;

    useEffect(() => {
        canvas = canvasRef.current;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        
        setSize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', setSize);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        return () => {
        }
    }, []);

    function setSize() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function render(time) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const x = canvas.width / 2 + Math.sin(time * .005) * 100;
        const y = canvas.height / 2;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size); // <-- Size is not updating here

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    return <div><canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>{ size }</div>
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a state into a function, it will always be the initial state, because when react rerenders it loses the reference, to avoid that you need to use a ref inside the funciton, and make it update in every rerender:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useControls } from 'leva';

export default function SquareCanvas() {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const { size } = useControls({
        size: { value: 10, min: 1, max: 50 },
    });

    const sizeRef = useRef(size);

    let canvas, ctx;

    useEffect(() => {
        canvas = canvasRef.current;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        setSize();
        window.addEventListener('resize', setSize);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        requestAnimationFrame(render);

        return () => {
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        sizeRef.current = size;
    })

    function setSize() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    function render(time) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const x = canvas.width / 2 + Math.sin(time * .005) * 100;
        const y = canvas.height / 2;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, sizeRef.current, sizeRef.current);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    return <div> <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas> </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes so much sense! And would it make any difference to provide "size" in the dependency array? Like: useEffect(() => { sizeRef.current = size; }, [size])

Comment: Your welcome! Good point! You could add size to the dependency array.